# Create a thumbnail from an UIViewController without it showing

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm making an Ipad application that consists of some 100 different views that represent projects. To be able to scroll fast between projects I am trying to create a thumbnail view. 
The problem is that I have to make the thumbnail images before the UIViewController itself is shown on screen.

Currently I'm using this code:

```
ProjectViewController2 * page2 = [[ProjectViewController2 alloc]initWithNibName:@"ProjectViewController2" bundle:nil displayRightArrow:FALSE media:nil];
[page2 setMyMedia:media];
[page2 configurePage];
CGSize size = [page2.view bounds].size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
[[page2.view layer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
NSString * filePath= [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Documents/project/%@", [media fileName]];
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0) writeToFile:filePath atomically:TRUE];
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This works, I get a screenshot from the UIViewController, but without the main images. These images are not being set in the NIB file, but in the configurePage function. The background color and menubar, that are being set in the NIB file, are visible in the thumbnail.

I suspect that I don't see the images because the UIViewController is not being shown on screen and thus some kind of draw function is not being called.

Any help is really appreciated!!!

Stijn

Answer (score 0):

When is the configurePage method being called? On ViewDidLoad?Where as the ProjectViewController is initialised with initWithNibName, hence probably why the nib elements are showing and you can get a image representation of them. My guess is write a custom initiailiser which has the project image as part of the initialisation sequence, or perhaps test moving the configurePage code to one of the other viewController methods such as viewWillAppear. Just a thought.

Comment: The configurePage methode is called right after the page is constructed. See the code snippet at line 3